# What is the link between Camera Interface with the Phone's Background operation and Garbage Collection?

Tags: android, memory, camera

When I try to scan the QR/Barcode. Initialized the Camera but the scan was not working. When I saw the log it has lots of Garbage clearance information. Once all the GC was done. The QR/Barcode scan works perfectly and the strange thing was with the strong network or no network the scan is instant but with the poor network. It takes ages to do it.

> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark-sweep GC freed 5614(449KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(288KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1691KB/2MB, paused 5.354ms total 10.731ms W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15(or any other number)ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using api 24 and higher you need to add permission to picker intent,
Also bitmap occupies to much memory, hence after the use of bitmap is over you need to bitmap.recycle();